# Sessions in PHP 5.3.3 and kirby

Tags: php, session, kirby

## Situation

I have implemented a modified version of the kirby Auth plugin on a client website, it basically works this way

- User accounts are simple kirby content files with the title serving as the login and a password field containing a bcrypt encrypted version of the users password
- On the website, visitors can click on "Customer Area", which goes to a template managed by the modified auth plugin (which redirects to the "login" form).
- The website is multilingual. So the accounts file will look like `content/extranet/login/login.fr.txt` or as an example `content/extranet/bastian/bastian.fr.txt`, this is what the modified Auth plugin is looking for, it finds the file and reads it, checks the password, and the logins the users.
- This system requires account pages title to be the same as their URL, and to always be invisible pages
- User is logged in and can only see in the « secure » template the files present in his folder

This all works good here on my local MAMP server as you can see in the screenshots, but on the production server http://www.driving-evolution.com, this doesn’t work, and i don’t know why, i have looked in a lot of places and i don’t understand what is going on. (it doesn’t work on the staging server either)

On the production server, wether you enter a good or a bad login, the form doesn’t show any error message, and doesn’t log the user in either. At first i thought this is maybe because of my bcrypt install, but it is not, as i disabled it (and used plain passwords instead) and it still didn’t work.

The issue seems NOT to be from the plugin here but from a difference between my live PHP stack and local php stack (my guess is on the php session handling).

Remote PHP is 5.3.3

Here is a sample output of CURL on both installations :

#### WORKING (Local)

```
curl -d "username=test&password=test" -i devo.loc/fr/login

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 27 May 2014 12:59:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.5.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.3
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9249a942248a2382d8eb10090bf5d825; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: authFrontend=mc06csp25; expires=Wed, 28-May-2014 12:59:49 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=b38ec0b342356c2c38778e4a6925f085; path=/
Set-Cookie: authFrontend=8qyyn; expires=Wed, 28-May-2014 12:59:49 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/
Location: http://devo.loc/fr/extranet
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

#### FAILING (Remote)

```
curl -d "username=test&password=test" -i www.driving-evolution.com/fr/login

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 27 May 2014 13:01:32 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6j9o1i4djetojtbg444i51efm7; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Connection: Keep-Alive, close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

### USEFUL LINKS

REMOTE PHPVER : http://www.driving-evolution.com/phpver.php

### SCREENSHOTS when it works on local

[image: login-good]
[image: login-done]

Hope someone will be able to help me on this ! Ask for any further info and i will give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it WAS a problem with the CMS, file caching was turned on and not ignoring the "login", "logout", and "extranet" files (all related to customer area), had to add :

```
c::set('cache.ignore', array('api', 'sitemap', 'extranet', 'account', 'login', 'logout'));
```

to my kirby config (api and sitemap are unrelated).

This fixes the problem as the login form was cached and thus not hitting anything on the server. Now form is not cached.